# How to enable '"Enable Milestone Feed Items" in scratch org through metadata file or configuration

Tags: salesforcedx

[image]How to enable Enable Milestone Feed Items,Show the time remaining in actual hours, not business hours, and Enable stopped time and actual elapsed time in scratch org through metadata file or configuration

Comment: Your question needs to contain *both* a clear statement of your issue and the relevant source code. When you include source code, you must use the `{}` tool in the editor to format it. Commenters believed that you destroyed your own post because your XML rendered as a series of true and false values. Please take some time to read [ask] and try again to [edit] your question, *without* deleting what is already there. I've rolled back the last change.

Answer (score 0):

Look for **Entitlement Settings** in the Config

Feature Settings -> Service-> Entitlement Management -> Entitlement Settings

[image]

You should check the checkbox Enable Entitlement Management and Save.

After that, you will have the option to change the Entitlement config.

Metadata:

```
<types>
    <members>Entitlement</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93893/discussion-on-answer-by-m-peixoto-how-to-enable-enable-milestone-feed-items-i).

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code under Setting folder create Entitlement.settings-meta.xml file and retrive data from your org. This will pull metadata for above requirment

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/372657/edit) your answer to elaborate - you state how to pull down metadata, but you do not explain how to then actually enable what the OP wants enabled per the original question.